# How to rewrite a code, so i can run it on Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I want to create barcodes in an .pdf - file.
I search the web and found the following javascript code, but this seems to be not functional in Adobe Acrobat DC. So how can i rewrite this code, so that this code is running on Adobe Acrobat DC?

```
var rawData = this.getField("Sendungeins").valueAsString;
var out = this.getField("Barcodeeins"); 

function getBarcode(rawData) { 

var offset = 32; 
var highAscii = 18; 
var newCodeString = new Array(rawData.length + 3);

newCodeString[0] = offset + highAscii + 104; 
var total = 104; 

for(var stringCounter = 0 ; stringCounter < rawData.length ; stringCounter++) { 

var character = rawData.substr(stringCounter, 1); 
var ASCIIValue = character.charCodeAt(0); 
var checkDigit = ((ASCIIValue - offset) * (stringCounter + 1)); 
total += checkDigit; 
newCodeString[stringCounter + 1] = ASCIIValue; } 

var check = total % 103; 
var holder = 0; 

if(check + offset >= 127) { holder = check + offset + highAscii; } 
else { holder = check + offset; } 
newCodeString[newCodeString.length - 2] = holder; 
holder = 106 + offset + highAscii;
newCodeString[newCodeString.length - 1] = holder; 

for(var rCounter = 0; rCounter < newCodeString.length ; rCounter++) {
if(newCodeString[rCounter] == 32) { newCodeString[rCounter] = 128; } }
return getBarcodeText(newCodeString);
}
function getBarcodeText(codeString) { 
var returnVal = "<p align = \"center\"style=\"font-size:16.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:16.0pt;font-family:Code128bWinLarge\">";
for(var counter = 0 ; counter < codeString.length ; counter++) {
var intValue = codeString[counter]; returnVal += "&#" + parseInt(intValue); } returnVal += "</P>"; 
return returnVal;
}

out.value = writeIn(getBarcode(rawData));
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @doveyg no, nothing, with this code i get no errors, but the field "out" is empty. if i edit the last line into "out.value = (getBarcode(rawData));" the "out"-field is filled with "<p align = \"center\"style=\"font-size:16.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:16.0pt;font-family:Code128bWinLarge\">";

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the function `getBarcodeText(codeString)` is absolutely correct. However, the initial value of the `returnVal` variable is set up for HTML forms.

In PDF, you set the field (text) properties in the Field Properties dialog. That said, you would initialize the variable like this:

```
var returnVal = "" ;
```

In the loop, the HTML script adds (decimal) character codes, preceeded by "&#". This construct is not available in Acrobat JavaScript; you might instead use the `fromCharCode()` method to get the character, which then should display properly using the according font.

There may be further modifications needed, but this should get you closer. You might, for debugging purposes, show the values either in an `app.alert()` dialog, or write them to the Console with `console.println()` .

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have no idea, how the code has to look, or how to edit this. I would be most grateful if you could help me further.